# Philosophy books for decision theory and economics idea

Tags: reference-request, self-study, decision-theory, philosophy-of-economics

I have learned economics so far, the most astonishing economics' thing is its though which is talkable and visually in the real world or the abstract world that is worth researching and talking. What I see in common is the abstract ideas that are generated from philosophy and economics is the social science study, I am interested in both philosophy and economics but what I only know and read is economics' side, not philosophy's side.

Does anyone recommend any book worth for spending the time to gain both sides of knowledge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I ask your level of education? If you're an undergraduate student just getting going in the field -- keep these thoughts you have in mind but don't dwell on them yet. I was like you and saw the lens through economics courses being taught was exceedingly devoid of psychological basis.

When getting into a Ph.D. program, it starts to become clearer these ideas you call 'economics' ideas are in-fact very much rooted in consumer psychology. The models will become more intricate for these reasons. But if you want to see the scope, I'd suggest you look up a text on Demand Theory. For now, if you're just getting going -- I would focus almost entirely on mathematics and take the theory as an exercise. You'll get good enough at math where a model/equation turns into an abstract metaphor. (This is where these philosophical ideas finally take an important place).

The most important thing for economics I can't stress this enough, but learn mathematics.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My first thought is as you said but as time pass after I saw behavioral economics or ecological rationality that mathematics is not purely the solution to understanding the economics behavior. I choose this path and someone said it might not lead me to that goal and right now I am indecision whether read which one math or philosophy but both is not the solution I have scarcity and other things to do. I don't know I am good at math but economics is not purely about math but the analytical of social science so, please answer me

Comment: You right economics is about people and their behavior. But you see, if you study only philosophy and more esoteric abstractions of human behavior -- you may conclude with some meaningful insights no doubt. But these conclusions would be nothing more than unproven ideas with very little application. Math allows you to modify a phenomenon, reproduce it and test it. That said, although it settles some confusion bear in mind some would argue economics is still a bunch of unproven abstractions. Nonetheless

Comment: Thank you so much, I am an undergraduate student who recently talks to philosophy-mind student and lost the point of argument. I don't know whether this is the best way but I know math is still important, he and I do not share the same goal but philosophy or human itself is also the good way to describe economics. I thought as what if I can prove any single equation but cannot create one that is something terrify me since that day of arguing. My dream goal is to create one contribution to economic theory, so I think I lost when things become like this anything support him, the odds against me.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little bit unclear. But still, if you wish to delve into the philosophical side of economical topics/question/phenomena, you can check the Stanford Encyclopaedia of Philosophy's [article on Philosophy of economics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/economics/). It might be a good place to start and refine what you are looking for.

Comment: Do you ever curious what is economics for you? I love economics but cannot answer this question, I felt lost and want to discover what is economics itself and in my version.